# Can't login to wordpress admin says "insufficient permissions to access this page";

Tags: wordpress

I had a wordpress install on wordpress 4.3 and it got hacked so i moved the website to wordpress 4.5 by doing a fresh install, Now i replaced some tables in database including posts table wp_options and wp_taxenomy and taxanomy relations table. 
The problem is that the website works fine, but when i try to login to the admin page i get not enough permissions to access this page. So i think i have some problems in my wp_options.

I tried disabling all the plugins through database, changing htaccess file, changing file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

within your database, look at the values in the wp_usermeta table as follows:

wp_capabilities should be a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}

wp_user_level should be 10

Comment: did it, doesn't work still, thanks for the answer though

Comment: also the new database had a different table prefix if that can help

Comment: Send me your usermeta table's dump sql file and the username using which you are trying to login.